# which are the valid .htaccess directories

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any need for .htaccess files in directories higher than that where index.html is placed?

I found such a file one level higher after a FileZilla accident (my fault; not Filezilla's) and suspect it should be deleted.

Comment: It not clear what you mean. Can you add some examples and clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess file has an effect on [the directory it's in and all the descendent directories](http://cscie12.dce.harvard.edu/lecture_notes/2007-08/20080423/slide61.html). You would need another .htaccess in a sub-folder if it was altering rules or adding new ones to what was inherited from its parent directory.

To expand on this based on more info from below: If the .htaccess files are in directories above your hosting dir, they will have an effect. However you should not amend or delete files on shared servers that you don't have direct authorization to. Check with your host or sysadmin - maybe those files need to be there, or perhaps they can be tidied up. In any case you can override .htaccess rules with a .htaccess file in the subdirectory.

Comment: Note that some versions of Apache are looking for .htaccess even beyond DocumentRoot, all the way to the root directory of the filesystem (this bit me once, not sure if it's still the default behavior).

Comment: unaesthetic, you are implying or perhaps stating that .htaccess can have effects at `/`, `/home`/, `/home/userName`, and also `/home/userName/public_html`, where it is only `/home/userName/public_html` that contains an index.php or similar file.

Comment: @H2ONaCl the index file shouldn't make a difference - .htaccess controls how the apache server responds to requests. let's say you had an empty dir `/example/` on your root, and a .htaccess on your root with a rule for a custom 404 page. navigating to `/example/missing-file.html` would still be redirected to your 404 page. If the .htaccess in your higher-level dir has rules in it, it will affect `/`, `/home/` etc.

Comment: Where's the apache configuration that determines that the root will be searched for .htaccess?

Comment: You mean httpd.conf? I believe its location depends on your Apache installation and setup, you need to check your own server. It's not a given that you'll have access to this, you need to talk to whoever admins your server if you can't find it.

Comment: This is a shared server. I don't see httpd.conf.

Comment: In that case it's very unlikely you'll be able to access it. Also you should not do anything with the .htaccess files outside of your own directories without checking with the sys admins first.